# Migrated to Namecheap, now Trouble with Database & wp-config

Tags: database, mysql, sql, hosting

I have been using a free web host while I set up my WP site. Now that it's all done I went and bought hosting from Namecheap.

I uploaded the site and WordPress and everything seems to look fine, but I think I may have problems with my WP database. I couldn't figure out a way to import my old sql database which I have saved. So now my wp-config file is connected to my old sql database from the free host. My site still displays normally, but I'm guessing this will cause problems somewhere down the road.

After this, I created a new database, user, and password from my Namecheap cPanel. However, with Namecheap there is no option to choose a host and it didn't tell me what the host was. So I took my old wp-config file and updated the database's name, user, and password. I left host a lone and it's still left as my old host before I switched to Namecheap hosting. With this wp-config file uploaded, the site again loads normally.

So with either wp-config file the site loads properly, but I don't think it's set up properly. Does anyone know what I should put for host in my wp-config file for Namecheap? Also, will I be fine using my newly created database for Namecheap or do I need to import my old database from the free host?

If I do need to import the database, how do I do that? I don't see any obvious options for it in the cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I changed the host value in wp-config to 'localhost' and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the import/export tools available from wordpress itself.  Maybe try a clean 
install and import your data from there.  It will be a better and more clean migration.

Your import/export Tools will be in Admin->Tools.

If you are looking to import a MySQL database from a MySQL dump, (filename.sql), you can do that from CPanel by going into PHPMyAdmin.  From the main screen, go to the Import Tab, browse for your file, and click the "Go" button.

Also, check out this reference to moving WordPress.  It's got some great advice in there as well. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Had you gone with a real host they would have done it for you.  Even HostGator is better than NameCheap.  If they are a cPanel host you shouldn't have to select the host name you can use the one that comes in the file.  That works on Host Gator as well.

I have dozens of WordPress sites.  Find a host that offers real backend services it's worth it.  And you really don't pay much if anything for it. Just get a Reseller account so you can stack each new domain on the existing account and not incur additional costs.

You get what you pay for.  Sorry, but NameCheap is just not a top tier host.

There are specific instructions on moving from server to server on the WordPress.org Website.

Bottom line is the fix you need is a 1 minute fix on the backend that your host should do for you.

Comment: who would you recommend? I'm split about 50/50 between WordPress sites and sites that I code.